# How to run multiple functions one after another in Vue.js?

Tags: javascript, function, methods, vuejs2

I am using two functions, one to move a set of questions to the next question and the other to move a progress bar on. The question that moves the user to the next question overrides the first function and the `progressBar` function doesn't process.

There are no errors shown and I have changed the order or the functions and having one big function all have to the same result. If I run the functions separately both functions work perfect. They originate from `@onClick` on a button.

```
     nextQuestion: function(item){

       var newKey = item + 1;

       var y = document.getElementById('question' + item);

        var x = document.getElementById('question' + newKey);

        if (y.style.display === 'block') {
            y.style.display = 'none';
            x.style.display = 'block';
            console.log("Changed");
        } else {
            console.log("ERROR");
        };

      },

      progressBar: function(item){

        this.percentQuestion = 100/this.numberQuestions;

        var elem = document.getElementById("myBar");

        var numericWidth = elem.style.width.replace(/\D/g,'');

        var currentWidth = +numericWidth;

        var newWidth = +numericWidth + +this.percentQuestion;

        var id = setInterval(frame, 10);
        function frame() {
          if (currentWidth >= newWidth) {
            clearInterval(id);
          } else if(currentWidth < 100){
            currentWidth++;
            elem.style.width = currentWidth + '%';
              }
              else{
                console.log('max');
              };
          };

        this.nextQuestion(item);

     },
```

Comment: This is not a Vue question. You need promises.

Comment: Could you put up a jsfiddle?  I suspect that you are setting this up in an imperative way and you could clean it up quite a bit by being more declarative, without seeing it though i can't give you the full thoughts on it.

Comment: I am consuming a lot of internal api's in a dev environment to get to this point so would be quite tricky... Is there anything you can see that could cause a problem, or should I implement promises? @Austio

Comment: I suspect the fundamental problem is that you are using the functions to manipulate the dom.  If you derived the dom view from data and then just changed that data from the onClick then it would probably be easier to reason about and do exactly what you want.  Super general but hope that helps.